# Wait For Data Inside a Listener in a Coroutine

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlinx.coroutines

I have a coroutine I'd like to fire up at android startup during the splash page.  I'd like to wait for the data to come back before I start the next activity.  What is the best way to do this?  Currently our android is using experimental coroutines 0.26.0...can't change this just yet.

UPDATED: We are now using the latest coroutines and no longer experimental

```
onResume() {
    loadData()
}

fun loadData() = GlobalScope.launch {
    val job = GlobalScope.async {
        startLibraryCall()
    }
    // TODO await on success
    job.await()
    startActivity(startnewIntent)
}

fun startLibraryCall() {
    val thirdPartyLib() = ThirdPartyLibrary()
    thirdPartyLib.setOnDataListener() { 
        ///psuedocode for success/ fail listeners
        onSuccess -> ///TODO return data
        onFail -> /// TODO return other data
    }
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The first point is that I would change your loadData function into a suspending function instead of using `launch`. It's better to have the option to define at call site how you want to proceed with the execution. For example when implementing a test you may want to call your coroutine inside a `runBlocking`. You should also implement [structured concurrency](https://medium.com/@elizarov/structured-concurrency-722d765aa952) properly instead of relying on `GlobalScope`.

On the other side of the problem I would implement an extension function on the `ThirdPartyLibrary` that turns its async calls into a suspending function. This way you will ensure that the calling coroutine actually waits for the Library call to have some value in it.

Since we made `loadData` a suspending function we can now ensure that it will only start the new activity when the `ThirdPartyLibrary` call finishes.

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*
import kotlin.coroutines.*

class InitialActivity : AppCompatActivity(), CoroutineScope {
    private lateinit var masterJob: Job
    override val coroutineContext: CoroutineContext
        get() = Dispatchers.Main + masterJob

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        masterJob = Job()
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        masterJob.cancel()
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        this.launch {
            val data = ThirdPartyLibrary().suspendLoadData()
            // TODO: act on data!
            startActivity(startNewIntent)
        }
    }
}

suspend fun ThirdPartyLibrary.suspendLoadData(): Data = suspendCoroutine { cont ->
    setOnDataListener(
            onSuccess = { cont.resume(it) },
            onFail = { cont.resumeWithException(it) }
    )
    startLoadingData()
}
```

Comment: Okay that looks great.  but the library is a third party I have no access to the call.  All I can do is listen to a listener

Comment: This answer requires no changes to the library, it's built on exactly the ingredients you specified. What it does is show you how to use the listeners to construct a `suspend fun`. Once you have that, you don't need any `async-await` logic.

Comment: The coroutines stuff is still so new and has been changing constantly that I am still not sure of best practices.  But thanks this loots pretty good I'll test it out and see if I can get it working.

Comment: What is `suspendCoroutine`?

Comment: [suspendCoroutine](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.coroutines/suspend-coroutine.html) is a function that allows us to construct suspending coroutines from other types of code. In this case, it builds a suspending function from a third party library that uses callbacks

Answer (score 0):

You can use LiveData

```
liveData.value = job.await()
```

And then add in onCreate() for example

```
liveData.observe(currentActivity, observer)
```

In observer just wait until value not null and then start your new activity

```
Observer { result ->
            result?.let { 
                startActivity(newActivityIntent)
            } 
}
```

Comment: Google does not advocate using `job` API explicitly