# Return a Deferred type from Polidea bluetooth library - Kotlin Coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, bluetooth-lowenergy, kotlinx.coroutines

I'm doing some experiments with kotlin coroutines, in particular I would like to return to my coroutine a RxBleDevice from [polidea](https://github.com/Polidea/RxAndroidBle) library.
However, Polidea scanBleDevices function returns a Disposable on subscribe. Is there any way, according to my code, to return to my Coroutine a RxBleDevice?

This is my code, at the moment it doesn't compile:

```kotlin
val scanDevices: Deferred<RxBleDevice> = GlobalScope.async {

            rxBleClient.scanBleDevices(ScanSettings.Builder()
                .build(), filterBuilder.setDeviceName(bikeBleName).build())
                .subscribe(
                    { scanResult ->
                        // Process scan result here.
                        scanResult.bleDevice
                    },
                    { throwable ->
                        // Handle an error here.
                    }
                )
        }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait For Data Inside a Listener in a Coroutine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53161897/wait-for-data-inside-a-listener-in-a-coroutine)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to wrap the `subscribe` method call into the

```
suspendCancellableCoroutine< RxBleDevice>{ cont ->
  //your code here
}
```

block. In the `subscribe` callback implementation use `cont.resume()` to resume coroutine with result and `cont.resumeWithException` to resume it with an error.

You may also want to bind cancellation between your coroutine and the scan activity. See `cont.invokeOnCancellation {  }` for details.

The API you call looks like an Rx, maybe one of these modules help 
https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines/blob/master/reactive/README.md

Comment: Thanks, it works! Do you think that an extension function could be a way too?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Or you may create your own extension function that does the `subscribe` and suspend inside to make code easier to read